# Hash username and password for authenticate ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

How can l implement a hash function (SHA512) that encrypt the username and check if this username and password is correct in the SQL server?

Working login right now if you set a cleartext username

```
user = User.find_by(username: params[:session][:username].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  log_in user
  redirect_to :root
else
  flash.now[:warning] = 'Wrong username/password'
  render 'new'
end
```

I have tried encrypt the username before it runs the if statement but I can get it to work.
The way I hash the username is:

```
username = params[:session][:username].downcase
username_encrypted = Digest::SHA2.new(512).hexdigest(username)
```

any ideas how this can be made?

What i am trying to achieve with this is. Too have one column in SQL with encrypted usernames and another column with "public" usernames. Where public usernames is visible for everybody on the site and encrypted usernames is stored in SQL only for authentication.

Comment: Have you looked into the devise gem?  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Why would you want to hash username?

Comment: Yes and that function to encrypt username also doesn't exists in devise. Please correct me, if I am wrong. @Sergio Tulentsev i have one table for usernames for logins and another table where users have another public (visible for other users) username.

Comment: I mean what do you need it for? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve with this is. Too have one column in SQL with encrypted usernames and another column with "public" usernames. Where public usernames is visible for everybody on the site and encrypted usernames is stored in SQL only for authentication.

Comment: @Amidii: why not use "public" username for auth?

Comment: It's just a security safety. If people get access to login usernames and password, then they need to decrypt them before use.